# Не добавляется приложение (\appendix) в документ с пакетом NCC-LATEX

Tags: latex, tex

Я в MiKTeX 2.9, TeXnicCenter 2.02.(профиль компиляции LaTeX=>PDF) пытаюсь использовать пакет [NCC-LATEX](https://ctan.org/pkg/ncclatex) класс **book** для создания книги. К сожалению мне не удаётся использовать команду `\appendix`.
Например следующий код:

```
\documentclass[book
,a4paper
,14pt
,russian                                                                
,openright      
]{ncc}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         

\begin{document}    

\frontmatter                                                
\author{Автор}                                          
\title{Название}    
\maketitle                                                  
\tableofcontents                                        

\mainmatter                                                 
\chapter{глава}
Текст
\chapter{глава}
Текст
\chapter{глава}
Текст

\appendix                                                   
\chapter{Прил}
Текст приложения
\chapter{Прил}
Текст приложения

\end{document}
```

завершиться ошибкой (стандартный класс book данный пример нормально компилирует):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@Alph #1->\text {\cyr \@Asbuk
                               {#1}}
l.67 \chapter{Прил}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined. 

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   }
l.67 \chapter{Прил}   
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Использовать другие классы я не хочу, так как не разбираюсь в вёрстке, а автор класса NCC специально адаптировал его для отечественной вёрстки.

Я догадываюсь, что LaTeX не нравятся русские буквы в нумерации приложений, но что с этим сделать - ума не приложу.

Comment: Проблема не в русских буквах в нумерации приложений, а в том, каким образом автор пакета пытается их впихнуть. В стилевом файле (nccltrus) сделана попытка переопределения команд `\alph` и `\Alph` на `\asbuk` и `\Asbuk`. Возможно, во времена былинные (2006 год, однако) этот злой хак и работал, но сейчас, LaTeX его считает некорректным. Если не использовать параметр `russian`, то этот пакет все еще можно как-то использовать (а с приложениями - разбираться нормально переопределив стиль именно оформления приложений). В общем, без вмешательства в сам пакет. вряд ли это будет компилироваться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Без  параметра russian этот пакет наверное нет смысла использовать. Я написал его автору о проблеме, он обещал посмотреть. В то же время в английской ветке мне предложили [костыль](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419630/156887). На первый взгляд он работает.

Comment: @Vladimir, автор сказал, что его пакет NCC-LATEX больше не поддерживается. При этом автор говорит, что пакет hyperref частично поддержан, но без учёта раздела \frontmatter и \backmatter. 
Поэтому думаю, что новые книги все-таки надо начинать на других классах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В английской ветке [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) предложил [костыль](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419630/156887), который на первый взгляд работает.

```
\documentclass[book
,a4paper
,14pt
,russian
,openright
]{ncc}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\let \@Asbuk\russian@Alph
\let \@asbuk\russian@alph
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\author{Автор}
\title{Название}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{глава}
Текст
\chapter{глава}
Текст
\chapter{глава}
Текст

\appendix 
\chapter{Прил}
Текст приложения
\chapter{Прил}
Текст приложения

\end{document}
```